# How to delete cells in a range of a column in google app script using getLastRow() & shift

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been looking through stackoverflow for some help on how to script in google sheets a function that would allow me to remove empty cells in a range and shift them over (to the left) when completed. I've only seen questions regarding removing empty rows or columns instead of cells in a range.

*This is what the data looks like I'm trying to work with:*

[example google sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hMrG.png)

**I need to delete cells A1-A15 and shift over the other columns**.

What's currently working is the following code, however it will delete/shift over the column even if there is data in the column (A) that I'm having the function review (ex. data in cell A6).

**I want to ensure that this function doesn't go off if there is data in column A before the last and 2nd to last data entry as per the example.**:

```js
function blankRemoval(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('sheet1');//need to call sheet by name as I have multiple tabs
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
  var cellsBlank = sheet.getRange(1,1).isBlank();

  if(cellsBlank) {
  sheet.getRange(1,1,lastRow-3,1).deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.COLUMNS); // shifts cells left

  }//end of if
}//end of function
```

So with this in mind, I thought I could make the variable cellsBlank to use .getRange(1,1,lastRow-3,1) as well so that it only looks through the range to the last row, and stops 3 from the last row. However when I use this code, it doesn't delete the cells if there is data in them or not (the function runs without errors but nothing occurs).

I've tried a few different items to use on this but I'm running into a wall as I'm not a proficient programmer. My guess is that it needs to iterate, or I'm doing something wrong with the range.

**Also to note, there will always be 2 data entries in column A like my example, with data being one cell apart. This is a entry of sorts to help with historical review. I want to retain these two cells where they are, but shift the empty data above**

Comment: This line only checks the contents of A1, not the column: var cellsBlank = sheet.getRange(1,1).isBlank();

Comment: How should your result sheet look like?

Comment: @Laura Dye Ah, right! How do I enable it to look through a certain range then? I tried to use getRange (1,1,LastRow,1) but it didn't seem to work

Comment: @YuriKhristich just the columns B and over shifted to the left when the empty cells in Column A are removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it should be this:

```
function blankRemoval(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('sheet1');
  var col_A = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow()-3,1);

  if (col_A.getValues().flat().filter(String).length == 0) { // <-- if the col A is empty
    col_A.deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.COLUMNS);
  }
}
```

`.getValues()` get a 2d array with values

`.flat()` convert the 2d array into an 1d array

`.filter(String)` remove from the array all empty cells

`.length` get a length of the array

This way, if the range contains empty cells only the array will have no elements (array.length = 0)

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

**Update**

It turned out that some cells in column 'A' could contain spaces. Here is modified function that removes spaces from the range:

```
function blankRemoval(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('sheet1');
  var col_A = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow()-3,1);

  var contents = col_A.getValues().flat().join('').replace(/\s+/g,'');

  if (contents == '') col_A.deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.COLUMNS);
}
```

Comment: thanks for this and your time. I tried this function and it ran successfully (no errors occured) but it didn't delete the cells and shift.

I tried running it both with data in column A and without

Comment: Share copy of your sheet. It's only way to understand what's wrong. Since it works fine on my sheet. It removes cells in column A as intended. I just added two screenshots

Comment: sorry you were right it does work after I ran a clearContent through the same range. I think I just need to code the clearContent to not perform if there is data existing in the range already. So if I add a col_A.clearcontentI() into the function before the if statement, is the best way to make that run similar to the if statement you provided?

Comment: thank you so much this all worked! I used the if statement you set up with a clearContent and it's working like a charm

Comment: I've added the variant of the function that handles spaces in the range.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the best function to use for the question I posed thanks to @Yuri. The clearContent helps remove any entries that would prevent the deleteCells action to go

```js
function blankRemoval(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('sheet1');
  var col_A = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow()-3,1);
  
    if (col_A.getValues().flat().filter(String).length == 0) { 
    col_A.clearContent();} //<---checks if cell range is empty, and if so performs a clear content (this seemed to fix issues with any ghost entries)

  if (col_A.getValues().flat().filter(String).length == 0) { // <-- if the col A is empty
    col_A.deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.COLUMNS);
  }
}
```

Comment: But, as far as can tell, if you will clear all content from the range it removes the data in column 'A' that should (your initial condition) prevent to remove the range. Are you sure that is should work this way? What if there would be something in cell 'A6' for example?

Comment: @YuriKhristich I tested it with data in A6 and it did not perform the clear content action (until it was blank) so it seems to work, however you're suggestion for removing spaces is probably a better idea!